# Which is more efficient in JavaScript String

Tags: javascript

which on of these two is more efficient means which will give faster output
First One

```
outString =  "My First String";
outString += "My Second String";
outString += "My Third String";
outString += "My Fourth String";
outString += "My Fifth String";
myFinalString = outString;
```

Or Second One

```
outString =  "My First String"
          + "My Second String"
          + "My Third String"
          + "My Fourth String"
          + "My Fifth String";
myFinalString = outString;
```

In one of the screen I have make string like this which runs in more then 100 lines, So which will you suggest?

Comment: I think you're trying to optimize the wrong thing. While one of these syntaxes may indeed be better, I think the bigger problem is that you've got some massive string that you're trying to build up, and it's probably a sign of deeper architectural issues that are much more important to resolve than picking a string building syntax.

Comment: jsperf.com, you can check yourself. Although, the difference in efficiency will be negligible either way.

Comment: the 2nd one is probably faster on old systems

Comment: The second one is invalid javascript.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez: how so?, it runs in my chrome console just fine...

Comment: Copy and paste every code in this link: http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Comment: @Danny, that is a warning not an error. While it *is* bad JavaScript, it is not technically invalid.

Comment: I agree. It still works correctly on the console chrome too. However, a warning indicates that may not work properly in another browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome the performance is almost exactly the same:

[image: JSPerf]

Firefox shows similar results as well, so I would not worry about which syntax you use.

JSPerf Result: https://jsperf.com/javascript-string-test

Comment: So: It is premature optimization ....